# Passing Parameter though html server pages using '#'

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters

I am trying to pass a variable through an HTML page, and I got it working, but when I changed to a server, the HTML pages go from 'page1.html' to 'page1#' After this change I can no longer send parameters to my second page as they come out as 'undefined'. The passing of the variable works, it's just retrieving it.

The URL looks like this: http://localhost:1337/page1#?34

Here is the old working code on that no longer works:

```
        // Takes parameters from HTML address and passes it through
        var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
        queryString = queryString.substring(0);
        var queries = queryString.split("&");

        var placeHolder = queries[0];
        var Final = parseFloat(placeHolder)
```

I want to extract the number 34 from the URL and store it in a JS variable.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Why not regular query parameters ( ? ) ? Why the # ?

Comment: `The passing of the variable works, it's just retrieving it` this is most probably because # is treated as a end/comment and further data is not parsed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting your point if you want some data from one page to another, so you can use localstorage for example

//index1.html

```
<script>
   localStorage.setItem("item1", 34)
</script>
```

//index2.html

```
localStorage.getItem("item1")
   var item = localStorage.getItem("item1");
</script>
```